# Django. Using a variable as a part of a variable name

Tags: python, django, database, variables

I have a block of code that needs to be repeated over a hundred times with different input variables. The first 3 letters can change and the numbers can change. For example:

BTCH1_13 maybe become
BTCH1_18 or
MESH1_13

I would need to use (var x)H1_(var y) and somehow be able to input them.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this. Is there a term for this and how do I do it?

```
    </td>
    <td class="13">
      {% if BTCH1_13.isBreak == '!' %}!{% endif %}
      {% if BTCH1_14.isPUpFractal == 'pUP' %}pUP{% endif %}
      {% if BTCH1_14.isPDnFractal == 'pDN' %}pDN{% endif %}
      {% if BTCH1_15.isUpFractal == 'UP' %}UP{% endif %}
      {% if BTCH1_15.isDnFractal == 'DN' %}DN{% endif %}
      {% if BTCH1_14.isPSG == 'PSG' %}PSG{% endif %}
      {% if BTCH1_15.isSG == 'SG' %}SG{% endif %}
      <br>
      {{BTCH1_13.maxRetracement|default_if_none:""}}|{{BTCH1_13.Current_RP|default_if_none:""}}|{{BTCH1_13.maxProjection|default_if_none:""}}
    </td>
```

```
context = {
# ES
        "ESH4_01": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH4_1'),
        "ESH4_02": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH4_2'),
        "ESH4_03": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH4_3'),
        "ESH4_04": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH4_4'),
        "ESH4_05": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH4_5'),
        "ESH4_06": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH4_6'),
        "ESH1_0": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_0'),
        "ESH1_01": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_1'),
        "ESH1_02": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_2'),
        "ESH1_03": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_3'),
        "ESH1_04": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_4'),
        "ESH1_05": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_5'),
        "ESH1_06": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_6'),
        "ESH1_07": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_7'),
        "ESH1_08": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_8'),
        "ESH1_09": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_09'),
        "ESH1_10": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_10'),
        "ESH1_11": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_11'),
        "ESH1_12": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_12'),
        "ESH1_13": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_13'),
        "ESH1_14": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_14'),
        "ESH1_15": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_15'),
        "ESH1_16": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_16'),
        "ESH1_17": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_17'),
        "ESH1_18": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_18'),
        "ESH1_19": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_19'),
        "ESH1_20": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_20'),
        "ESH1_21": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_21'),
        "ESH1_22": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_22'),
        "ESH1_23": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='ESH1_23'),
#BTC
        "BTCH4_01": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH4_01'),
        "BTCH4_02": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH4_02'),
        "BTCH4_03": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH4_03'),
        "BTCH4_04": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH4_04'),
        "BTCH4_05": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH4_05'),
        "BTCH4_06": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH4_06'),
        "BTCH1_00": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_00'),
        "BTCH1_01": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_01'),
        "BTCH1_02": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_02'),
        "BTCH1_03": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_03'),
        "BTCH1_04": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_04'),
        "BTCH1_05": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_05'),
        "BTCH1_06": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_06'),
        "BTCH1_07": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_07'),
        "BTCH1_08": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_08'),
        "BTCH1_09": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_09'),
        "BTCH1_10": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_10'),
        "BTCH1_11": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_11'),
        "BTCH1_12": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_12'),
        "BTCH1_13": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_13'),
        "BTCH1_14": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_14'),
        "BTCH1_15": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_15'),
        "BTCH1_16": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_16'),
        "BTCH1_17": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_17'),
        "BTCH1_18": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_18'),
        "BTCH1_19": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_19'),
        "BTCH1_20": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_20'),
        "BTCH1_21": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_21'),
        "BTCH1_22": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_22'),
        "BTCH1_23": PeriodProperties.objects.get(PK='BTCH1_23'),
#GBP
#xxx
#etc - There will be many symbols sharing the same structure. The entire database is loaded into the context. It's not being populated using a for loop in the html, but rather being updated using the same primary keys.
}
```

Comment: how you are changing the variables ? is there any backend code which changes the variable ?

Comment: How are these variables populated in the context? Can you share the view

Comment: Updated the original post with an idea of what the context looks like.
I have a lot of database entries. I'm trying to figure out a way to enter them without typing them all out. Because if I want to make a small change, I'd then have to change it in every table cell.